# Can I copy values from other rows and column and automatically replace the missing values?

Tags: python, pandas

So, my dataframe is

```
    price   model_year  model           condition   cylinders   fuel    odometer    transmission    type    paint_color is_4wd  date_posted days_listed
0   9400    2011.0      bmw x5          good        6.0         gas     145000.0    automatic       SUV     NaN         True    2018-06-23  19
1   25500   NaN         ford f-150      good        6.0         gas     88705.0     automatic       pickup  white       True    2018-10-19  50
2   5500    2013.0      hyundai sonata  like new    4.0         gas     110000.0    automatic       sedan   red         False   2019-02-07  79
3   1500    2003.0      ford f-150      fair        8.0         gas     NaN         automatic       pickup  NaN         False   2019-03-22  9
4   14900   2017.0      chrysler 200    excellent   4.0         gas     80903.0     automatic       sedan   black       False   2019-04-02  28
```

As you can see, row 1's model is the same as row 3's, but row 1's model year is missing. It would naturally follow I can replace row 1's model year with row 3's so there isn't NaN there, and I'm aware I can manually change it, but the dataframe is over 50,000 rows long and there are many more values just like that Is there an automated way I can go about replacing these values like that?

Edit: After looking over the df just now, I've realized that I can't really replace the model year like that as it can change even within the same model, although I would still love to know how it's done if possible for future reference

Answer (score 0):

You can merge dataframe with itself and fillna it.

```py
df_want = df.merge(df[['model_year','model']].dropna().drop_duplicates(),on='model',how='left')

df_want['model_year'] = df_want['model_year_x'].fillna(df_want['model_year_y']

df_want = df_want.drop(['model_year_x','model_year_y'],axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can replace all NaN model years with the non-nan entry like this:

```
models = df['model'].unique()
for m in models:
    year = df.loc[(df['model_year'].notna()) & (df['model'] == m)]['model_year'].values[0]
    df.at[(df['model_year'].isna()) & (df['model'] == m), 'model_year'] = year
```